# Registration form done using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

This is my first time using Yii framework and I've never use a single PHP framework before. I've found a register form done using Yii framework from this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/27242-registration/

However, I'm not able to understand the whole thing. Below is the code from SiteController.php

```
/**
 * Displays the register page
 */
public function actionRegister()
{
        $model=new RegisterForm;
        $newUser = new User;

        // if it is ajax validation request
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
        {
                echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['RegisterForm']))
        {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['RegisterForm'];
                $newUser->username = $model->username;
                $newUser->password = $model->password;
                $newUser->email = $model->email;
                $newUser->joined = date('Y-m-d');

                if($newUser->save()) {
                        $identity=new UserIdentity($newUser->username,$model->password);
                        $identity->authenticate();
                        Yii::app()->user->login($identity,0);
                        //redirect the user to page he/she came from
                        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
                }

        }
        // display the register form
        $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

I'm not able to understand why there are no MySQL queries? I've never used a framework, and usually what I would do is write something like `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table values....");` to insert new data to the table.

What's the $newUser for? and how would $identity create new UserIdentity and authenticate? I'm confused by all these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to get familiar with Yii's MVC concepts (which are common among php frameworks):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices

`$newUser` (which is an instance of `User` class) inherits from Yii [Model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.model) class and is designed to make database queries (that's the purpose of Model in MVC), so you won't see any SQL in controller.

`$identity` is an instance of `UserIdentity` class, it inherits from [other built-in](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity) Yii class, the authentication-related one.

I suppose they are parts of [http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/](http://yii-user) extension.

All built-in Yii classes and their methods are well-documented, and Yii's official guide is quite good and exhaustive, it is a great place to start acquaintance with the framework.